# Start native time input from javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html

I need to get a time from the user on mobiles. I dont want to show the html input field to the user. I thought I could simulate a click or give focus to on an input field to start the native time picker. It does not seem to work. any Idea How to do that ?

I wrote this pen to try it on android. [codepen.io/kbenoit/pen/gJmay](http://codepen.io/kbenoit/pen/gJmay)

Basically clicking on a button triggers this code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("timeInput");
e.value = "8:00:00";
e.focus(); // or
e.click();
```

Where

```
<input id="timeInput" type="time"></input>
```

I know I can implement my own picker in html, but it would be simpler and prettier to use the native time picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using ionic (cordova and angular), I'm using this cordova [plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/#DatePicker) instead.